# Enviar date vazio para o ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho em meu **formulário** o seguinte **campo**:

```
<input type="date" class="inputTextMedio" name="dataBatismo" id="dataBatismo"/>
```

Se escolhida uma **data**, ele envia corretamente os dados para o **ajax** e a gravação no MySQL ocorre normalmente:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "_scripts/_php/_validacoes/cadastrarMembro.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {   
         dataCadastro : $("#dataCadastro").val(),
         nome : $("#nome").val(),
         apelido : $("#apelido").val(),
         nascimento : $("#nascimento").val(),
         telefone : $("#telefone").val(),
         celular : $("#celular").val(),
         bairro : $("#bairro").val(),
         endereco : $("#endereco").val(),
         email : $("#email").val(),
         sexo : $("#sexo").val(),
         estadoCivil : $("#estadoCivil").val(),
         dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
         bloqueado : $("#bloqueado").val(),
         batizadoFora : $("#batizadoFora").val(),
         usuario : $("#usuario").val(),
         senha : $("#senha").val()
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('Resultado');
        if (result[0] == "Erro")
            $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
        else
            $(".resposta").html(result[1]);
    }
});
```

Porém, caso não seja escolhida nenhuma data no campo, o `Ajax` não aceita nada e nem roda.

O que está errado aqui?

Um detalhe que talvez haja relevância aqui é que o **inspector**, quando NÃO escolhida uma data, nem envia uma linha que seja. Fica todo vazio!

Também fiz a tentativa abaixo mas sem sucesso:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? "null" : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

E assim:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? "NULL" : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

E assim:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? 'null' : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

E assim:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? 'NULL' : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

E assim:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? null : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

E assim:

```
dataBatismo : $("#dataBatismo").val() == "" ? NULL : $("#dataBatismo").val(),
```

Nada dá certo.

Será que terei que converter para texto?

Comment: tá usando algum tipo de mascara ou plugin no campo da data?

Comment: Tente `!$("#dataBatismo").val().trim() ? "null" : $("#dataBatismo").val(),`

Comment: o problema era no php. estou abrindo outra dúvida

Comment: abri: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355323/recebendo-campo-nulo-ou-%C3%A3o-nulo